# Makefile for simple C++ OpenGL program

Tags: c++, opengl, makefile

I'm trying to write a makefile for an OpenGL program written in C++ (OSX).

Right now, there is only the single file chess.cpp, but I expect to add other files to the project, so I'm trying to create a makefile that I can expand to handle new files as needed. I'm getting these errors:

`clang: error: no such file or directory: 'chess.o'`

`clang: warning: -framework GLUT: 'linker' input unused`

`clang: warning: -framework OpenGL: 'linker' input unused`

`make: *** [chess.o] Error 1`

This is the makefile that I created. It's borrowed from something that I normally use for C programs, so if it looks strange, that could be why. How can I make this work for my C++ project?

```
CC = g++
CFLAGS = -c -g -Wall -Wextra
DEPS =
LDFLAGS = -framework GLUT -framework OpenGL

all: chess

%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
        $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

chess.o: chess.cpp
        $(CC) -c chess.cpp chess.o $(LDFLAGS)

chess: chess.o
        $(CC) -o chess.o (LDFLAGS)

clean:
        rm chess
        rm *.o
```

Comment: You forgot the `-o` option on the line: `chess.o: chess.cpp
        $(CC) -c chess.cpp chess.o $(LDFLAGS)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of errors:

First:

```
%.o: %.cpp $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)
```

This compiles all `.cpp` files and everything in `$(DEPS)` into their respective `.o` files.

This makes the following line redundant: (although this line appends the linker flags, which the previous does not)

```
chess.o: chess.cpp
    $(CC) -c chess.cpp chess.o $(LDFLAGS)
```

Even so, the line has an error. It is missing the output file option `-o`. The correct syntax is:

```
chess.o: chess.cpp
    $(CC) -c chess.cpp -o chess.o $(LDFLAGS)
```

And finally:

```
chess: chess.o
    $(CC) -o chess.o (LDFLAGS)
```

This line is missing an input argument. Make doesn't know what to compile. Also you are using the dependency file name as output argument. The filename directly after option `-o` specifies the output. Also a `$` is missing at `(LDFLAGS)`. The correct syntax should read:

```
chess: chess.o
    $(CC) chess.o -o chess $(LDFLAGS)
```

Comment: Thanks. Someday I'll actually understand makefiles. Not sure why they are so confusing to me. I appreciate your help.

Comment: You normally append linker flags at the compilation stage (i.e. .cpp → .o), because there's no linkage happening at that time.